# What can be replaced by fileInputStream.available()?

Tags: java, java-io

When learning Java IO, I found that `fileInputStream` has an `availabl()` method, which can be equal to the file size when reading **local files**. So if you can directly know the size of the file, then in the case of the **need to read the entire file**, it is necessary to use `BufferedInputStream` to decorate it?
like this:

```java
      FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("F:\\test.txt");
      byte[] data=new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
      if (fileInputStream.read(data)!=-1) {
           System.out.println(new String(data));
      }
```

or

```java
   BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new 
   FileReader("F:\\test.txt"));
   StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
   for (String line;(line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null;){
       stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
   System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

or

```java
     BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("F:\\test.txt"));
     byte[] data=new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
     if (bufferedInputStream.read(data)!=-1) {
           System.out.println(new String(data));
      }
```

What are the pros and cons of these methods? Which one is better?
thx.

Comment: In terms of memory usage buffering would help because you'd not have to read all the content into memory first. That being said I'd go with the approach you're most familiar with - if all 3 work. However, IMO there's one major flow in all 3 snippets: you're not providing any info on the file's encoding so the part that converts the bytes to characters will use the system's default encoding. That _might_ be the correct one by chance but that's the problem: you're leaving it to chance.

Comment: If it is ever 'equal to the file size when reading local files', it is an accident, and it will cease to hold the moment you read even one byte from the file. All it does is tell you how many bytes can *presently* be read from the stream *without blocking,* which is a different kettle of fish altogether. There are *specific warnings* in the Javadoc *against* using it as you have above. There are existing ways to get the size of any file, if that's what you need. But you rarely do. You shouldn't try to load entire files into memory.

Comment: The first one is incorrect due to the usage of available(), as indicated above. And you're using a Stream instead of a Reader to read characters. The second one is incorrect because it removes all the end of lines from what you read. The third one is incorrect due to the usage of available(). Google for "Java IO tutorial". it has correct examples.

Comment: The third one is also incorrect because you're ignoring the read count returned by `read()`. Suppose you tell us what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: In short, buffering only helps if you have lots of short read/writes. It only adds overhead for large reads/writes. It's not magic ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong about the meaning of `available()`. It returns the possible number of bytes you can read *without blocking.* From documentation:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

So, if you want convert stream to byte array you should use corresponding libraries, such as [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html):

```
byte[] out = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
```

Comment: thanks for @user207421 editions. I edit one moment: available returns possible (not maximum) number of bytes, because according to documentation available returns `an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skiiped over)`